# Resizing a GIF when playing it as a background of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gif

I am playing a GIF on hover in my web page in the following manner:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CmBgofK7QzU/TVj3u3N1h2I/AAAAAAAADN8/OszBhGvvXRU/s640/tumblr_lg7h9gpbtP1qap9qio1_500.jpeg');
}

div:hover {
  background: url('http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/50-inspiring-animated-gifs/012.gif');
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to resize the GIF playing to fit the size of the div element? I purposely put a GIF in that example that is not big or is too big so it has to play a corner of the animation or it plays it multipe times next to each other to fill the space. http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/design/2013/09/Boglio_05.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after: `background-size: cover;`? Anyway, for more possibilities, you should just learn more about `background-size`, `background-position` and `background-repeat` for example.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CmBgofK7QzU/TVj3u3N1h2I/AAAAAAAADN8/OszBhGvvXRU/s640/tumblr_lg7h9gpbtP1qap9qio1_500.jpeg');
}

div:hover {
  background: url('http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/50-inspiring-animated-gifs/012.gif');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```